# Moving Angular controller functions to a separate Typescript class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working on an application using AngularJS and Typescript. Many requirements are being added to the application so I want to nail down the structure before the code gets out of hand.

I have an Angular controller with 1500 lines and I would like to move the functions to a separate file like so:

```
export class CtrlFunctions{
    private scope: any;

    constructor($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
    }

    updateHeader = header => {
        //more logic here
        this.scope.header = header;
    }
}
```

And I would access the values in the controller like this:

```
import { CtrlFunctions } from "../controller-functions/entry.ctrl.func";

namespace Entry {
    class EntryCtrl {
        private funcs: CtrlFunctions
        constructor(){
            this.funcs = new CtrlFunctions($scope);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way to take advantage of the modularity provided by Typescript?

Comment: This is related to AngularJS, not Angular, please edit the tag.